# EF Codefirst does method "afterModelCreating" exist?

Tags: c#, code-first

i have a problem with EF CodeFirst method. I need to create Index after the database is created. But method OnModelCreating is called too early (DB does not exist yet). Is there any "AfterModelCreating" method?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String.Format("CREATE INDEX IX_{0} ON {1} ({0})", "Text", "Table")); 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In EF versions before 4.3 you should configure a **Database Initializer**

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(new YourDbInitializer());
```

The initializer class may look like this:

```
public class YourDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DiorContextBase context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                "CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Username_Unique " +
                "ON dbo.Users(username)");
    }
}
```

In latest EF releases use migrations http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx